# How to remove an entry from localstorage in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, local-storage

I store some data in a *localstorage* in my Javascript file. I want to create a delete button on the details grid that allows me to *delete* an individual item. I need to first identify the key of the selected item and then use the `localStorage.removeItem(key)` method to delete the item. But my method doesn't seem to work.

**This is in my factory:**

```
removeItem: function (data) {
    var prefixLength = prefix.length;
    Object.keys(localStorage)
        .forEach(function (key) {
            if (key.substring(0, prefixLength) == data) {
                var item = window.localStorage[key];                            
                localStorage.removeItem(key);
            }
        });
},
```

**Then I call it in my controller.js:**

```
 $scope.remove = function () {
            expService.removeItem($scope.expense);
        },
```

**my button is:**

```
<button type="button"class="btn btn-sm btn-danger pull-right" id="remove" ng-click="remove()">
    <span class="glyphicons glyphicons-bin"></span>
</button></div>
```

Comment: What do you get ?

Comment: What is the error You are getting?

Comment: I click the button and nothing happens....the item is not removed

Comment: did you try to debug?

Comment: this doesn't delete a specific item from storage. For example, I want to delete a specific item when a button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to delete a localstorage data on button click. Here is how I achieved that.

```
<button onclick="deleteFavorite('Id or name what you set as key')"> Delete </button>


 function deleteFavorite(Id){
                     localStorage.removeItem(Id);
                }
```

Please note that you can add id dynamically to the function using javascript and you have to reload the page to see if the item is deleted or not.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt see error but simple to do it

```
<button type="button"class="btn btn-sm btn-danger pull-right" id="remove" ng-click="remove(expense)">
                    <span class="glyphicons glyphicons-bin"></span>
                </button>
```

and js

```
 $scope.remove = function (itemTodelete) {
             localStorage.removeItem(itemTodelete);
        },
```

Comment: I think something must be wrong with the removeItem function ....because it doesnt work and I dont see any error

Comment: did you run my function? if so you can test if its works by   localStorage.getItem(itemTodelete);

Comment: yes I used your changes and still it doesn't work :(

Comment: how do you know that it isn't working? do you check with debug? do you see any errors in the console? also you can check local storage via chrome browser tab...what browser you are testing

Answer (score 0):

```
localStorage.removeItem('itemTodelete');
localStorage.remove('itemTodelete'); or
localStorage.clear();
```